# Error Uncaught ReferenceError $ is not defined

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo este codigo, donde me marca error en esta linea $('#delete-contrato-select').on("click", function()

```js
function deleteCbContrato(id_tipo_contrato){     
             

        $('#id_tipo_contratoDelete').val(id_tipo_contrato );           
        
        $('#myModalDelete').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            $('#myInput').focus()
        });   
}


$('#delete-contrato-select').on("click", function(){

var r=$('#id_tipo_contratoDelete').val();

var parametros = {
                "r_delete" : r
        };
        $.ajax({
                data:  parametros,
                url:   'includes/funciones_catalogos.php',
                type:  'post',
                beforeSend: function () {
                        
                },
                success:  function (response) {
location.reload();
                }
        });
 });
```

Comment: Necesitas que el import de jquery esté arriba de tu script, muy probablemente lo tengas abajo, revisa si lo tienes de esa forma y de ser así, cámbialos de orden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás utilizando `$` que usualmente es la variable global que jQuery fija cuando lo cargas, por ejemplo, usando:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         ... tus funciones // supongamos que esto es el script de tu pregunta
      <script>
   </head>
   <body>
      ... shake your body ...
   </body>
</html>
```

Si no tienes `$` en el ámbito global, tu script va a tirar ese error.

Supongamos por ejemplo que tienes el siguiente código

```
var ManipulaDOM = function() {
      this.borraElemento = function(selector) {
          $(selector).remove();
      };
};
```

eso no tira ningún error. Pero si haces:

```
var manipulador = new ManipulaDOM();

manipulador.borraElemento('#mi_div');
```

El intérprete de javascript va a invocar `borraElemento`. Adentro se encuentra con `$` que no está definida dentro de `borraElemento`. Sigue buscándola subiendo en el Stack. Pero tampoco está definida en `ManipulaDOM`. Sigue subiendo por el stack hasta que llega al ámbito global, y si resulta que `window.$` no está definido, entonces arroja ese error.

Pese a que la mayoría de los sitios web que usan jQuery lo ponen en el `<head>` del documento, también es posible ponerlo al final del `<body>` (por todas esas buenas prácticas que explican que los scripts son bloqueantes y demoran la carga del DOM). Tú podrías hacer:

```
<body>
    <div id="mi_div">hola</div>
    <script>
        var ManipulaDOM = function() {
              this.borraElemento = function(selector) {
                  $(selector).remove();
              };
        };
    </script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var manipulador = new ManipulaDOM();

        manipulador.borraElemento('#mi_div');
    </script>
</body>
```

Y eso no arrojaría error, porque cuando declaras lo primero, todavía no ocupas `$` y cuando lo invocas, a esa altura `$` ya está en el ámbito global.

**Raya para la suma:** asegúrate de que jQuery se ha cargado **antes** de usar funciones que usan `$`. Y si esas funciones manipulan el DOM, también asegúrate de envolver todo el bloque en `$(document).ready(function() {  ...   });` o cualquiera de sus variantes.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo pude solucionar solo lo agrege en el codigo donde tenia '#delete-contrato-select'

Answer (score 0):

Creo que estás ejecutando la linea "$('#delete-contrato-select')...." antes de que se cargue jQuery.
Para evitarlo deberías ejecutar esa linea luego de cargarse jQuery, por ejemplo, así:

```
function deleteCbContrato(id_tipo_contrato) {
    $('#id_tipo_contratoDelete').val(id_tipo_contrato);
    $('#myModalDelete').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#myInput').focus()
    });
}

$(function () {
    $('#delete-contrato-select').on("click", function () {
        var r = $('#id_tipo_contratoDelete').val();
        var parametros = {
            "r_delete": r
        };
        $.ajax({
            data: parametros,
            url: 'includes/funciones_catalogos.php',
            type: 'post',
            beforeSend: function () {

            },
            success: function (response) {
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Suerte!

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo pude solucionar solo lo agrege en el codigo donde tenia '#delete-contrato-select'

Comment: Genial, me alegro.  Si la respuesta te sirvió por favor márcala para que pueda servirle a otros. Saludos.